# Can't hit "allow" in iOS Simulator >=8

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, core-location

I am writing a location-based app and whilst `[locMgr requestAlwaysAuthorization];` works on my iOS 9 iPhone 5c and on simulators of SDK 7.1 I simply can't hit "allow" on the simulators for SDK8 and 9.

The button is not highlighted when pressed, there is simply no feedback at all. I also can't go back through CMD+SHIFT+H as it is a system dialog.

I can allow location services in the settings in order to test my app but I'd like to see this procedure working in the simulator, too.[image]

Comment: It should be working.  I haven't seen this issue before.  Please file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com, including a sample application that exhibits this problem.

Comment: It's now working again, after several restarts and simulator resets. I guess it's got something to do with using iOS 9 symbols in Xcode 6 but I cannot reproduce the error anymore. Let's see how much views this questions gets - maybe it was some weird behavior only caused by my machine.